# Динамическое добавление полей в форму Yii2

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, yii, yii-bootstrap

Имеется форма с одним полем(textInput). При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" появляется ещё одно поле(textInput). Как можно это реализовать, при этом чтобы можно было считать каждое поле? Т.е. в конец форму добавлять еще одно поле, по нажатию кнопки "Добавить".
https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform - не помогло

Форма задается так:

```
< ?php $f = ActiveForm::begin()? >

< ?=$f->field($form, 'name')->textInput()->label('');? >

< ?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['id'=>'future', 'name' => 'button_add']) ? >
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Кнопка "Добавить"

```
 <button name="row_add" id="add_row">Добавить</button>
```

Форма добавление:

```
class FormAdd extends Model
{
    public $name;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name'], 'required', message => ''],
            ['name', 'default', message => ''],
        ];
    }
```

SiteController:

```
public function actionStorage()
{
         $form = new FormAdd();
        if (($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) && ($form->validate())){
             $name = Html::encode($form->name);
        }
        return $this->render['storage', ['form'=>$form, 'name'=>$name]];
 }
```

Comment: как https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform могло вам не помочь ? 
https://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo2/create вот же готовый пример того что вам нужно, нажимаете New и в конец формы добавляется поле :)

Comment: У меня проблема с установкой этой библиотеки, используемая в первой ссылке, вторая ссылка тоже использую такую же библиотеку

Comment: Так может вам проще будет разобраться с установкой чем придумывать велосипед ?

Answer (score 1):

видимо надо вместо

```
public $name;
```

сделать `public $name = [];`

в самой форме

```
< ?=$f->field($form, 'name[]')->textInput()->label('');? >
```

Тогда будет ожидаться массив значений, а не 1.
Ну а добавление поля - это просто js. Можно ajax запрос кидать и формировать на сервере используя Html helper.

Ну и для валидации использовать each

```
[
   // checks if every category ID is an integer
   ['name', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
]
```